# iPad Pro 9.7'' won't upgrade to ios11

Tags: ipad, ios

My iPad Pro does not seem to be willing to upgrade to ios11.

`General > Software Upgrade` says `ios 10.3.3 - Your software is up to date`.

I had previously enrolled to the beta program, although I had never been able to get any beta version. Thinking this might be the cause I removed it from `Profiles`.

How can I update, or how can I troubleshoot the situation?

Comment: Have you tried updating through iTunes ??

Comment: @ReneLarsen Not yet, I completely forgot about itunes. Good point, I'll try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that happens every release is that Apple rolls out the new os in stages. If you imagine Apple has one thousand update servers, it starts with a few and then rolls out the catalog of available updates to more and more servers.

Anecdotally, it’s rare for an update check to not see the update within 24 hours in the US but I certainly have seen some cases where a non-major update (say 10.2.1 to 10.2.2) didn’t fully propagate or be offered for almost 4 days after “release” that eventually was offered.

If you need an update, using iTunes to force it is one option of your over the air server isn’t ready to provide the update you expect. Before resorting to iTunes or just waiting, I would also reboot your device once or twice in case it’s just some corruption on the running os and also free up 4 GB of storage if you might be running low on space to hold the download and data that needs to migrate during the upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

Try iTunes to update your iPad Pro to latest iOS 11 first. If iTunes doesn't prompt you there is a new version to update, then you will have to use software which will install iOS 11 onto your iPad Pro.